# Generate array of numbers between a min and max value but also with a fix interval between 2 values

Tags: javascript

I have the following data structure and I need to create an array of numbers that matches given configuration:

```
{
  min: 1000,
  max: 10000,
  interval: 1000
}
```

What would be a proper function that outputs below array:

```
[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000]
```

It can be done through a for loop:

```
const output = [];
for (let i = input.min; i <= input.max; i += input.interval) {
  output.push(i);
}
console.log(output)
```

But I want to see if there's a cleaner way to do this using something like:

```
new Array((max - min + interval)).fill(undefined).map((_, i) => (i + min))
```

Comment: what effort have you made to solving the problem - hint: its like a `for` loop

Comment: @DanielA.White yes it's easy to do it through a `for` loop but I wanted to see if there's an easier way like - 
```console.log(new Array((max -min +interval)).fill(undefined).map((_, i) => (i + min)))```

Comment: @trurohit [It's possible](https://jsfiddle.net/jx01nzdw/) "without a loop" (internally it will still loop of course), but you have to ask yourself whether it becomes better readable/maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

Using `for` loop, it can be done simply.

```js
const input = {
  min: 1000,
  max: 10000,
  interval: 1000
};

const output = [];
for (let i = input.min; i <= input.max; i += input.interval) {
  output.push(i);
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you @Derek, I was trying to avoid a loop though. Was looking for an easier way like - `console.log(new Array((max -min +interval)).fill(undefined).map((_, i) => (i + min)))`