# Generate array of numbers between max and min value with an interval between 2 values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following data structure and I need to create an array of numbers that matches given configuration -

```
{
  min: 1000,
  max: 10000,
  interval: 1000
}
```

What would be a proper function that outputs below array -

```
[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000]
```

It can be done through a for loop -

```
const output = [];
for (let i = input.min; i <= input.max; i += input.interval) {
  output.push(i);
}
console.log(output)
```

But I want to see if there's a cleaner way to do this using Array.fill & map -

```
new Array((max - min + interval)).fill(undefined).map((_, i) => (i + min))
```

Comment: You're asking the [exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625055/javascript-generate-array-of-numbers-between-a-min-and-max-value-but-also-with) twice. Why?

Comment: @Andreas StackOverflow closed this other question and asked me to make it clearer and post it again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can figure out how many items should be in the result by dividing the difference between max and min by the interval, then create the array with `Array.from`, using the mapper's index to figure out how much to add to the `min` for each value of the array:

```js
const min = 1000,
  max = 10000,
  interval = 1000;

const length = (max - min) / interval + 1;
const arr = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => min + i * interval);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This looks much cleaner. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Get the array's length by rounding up `(max - min) / interval`. Get each step's value by multiplying the current index (`i`) by the `interval` and add the `min`.

```js
const fn = ({ min, max, interval }) =>
  new Array(Math.ceil((max - min) / interval)) // the array's length as a function of max, min, and interval
    .fill(undefined)
    .map((_, i) => (i * interval + min)) // a step is a product of i and interval + min


const result = fn ({
  min: 1000,
  max: 10001,
  interval: 1000
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread operator to generate the required array.

```js
const min = 1000;
const max = 10000;
const interval = 1000;
const ret = [...Array((max - min) / interval + 1)].map(
  (_, i) => min + interval * i
);
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's cleaner, but an interesting approach would be to use a generator. One example inspired from the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

```js
function* makeRangeIterator(start = 0, end = 100, step = 1) {
    while(start <= end) {
        yield start;
        start += step
    }
}

const sequenceGenerator = makeRangeIterator(1000, 10000, 1000);

//you have to loop through the generator
for(let value of sequenceGenerator) {
    console.log(value)
}
```